# How to compile dlib 19.2 in visual studio 2015 without using cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, dlib

I am using Dlib for face landmark detection for my academic project.

When I am running Dlib 19.2 `face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp` file in Visual Studio 2015 express, I wasn't able to get the results.

The steps followed

1. Created new project.
2. Added existing `face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp` and `source.cpp` file from `dlib\all` folder and added same files to project folder
3. In VC++ directories added this path `D:\dlib-19.2\dlib-19.2` as Include Directories.
4. Downloaded `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` file.
5. In the command line argument 'shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat  download.jpg' here shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat  i have added in project folder and download.jpg is my image file .
6. Added `dlib/external` folder to project.
7. Added  `#define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT`

Questions: So many errors in file and not able to understand what is happening.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is not inheriting the include directorys. I think you set "D:\dlib-19.2\dlib-19.2" as the *only* include dir. Errors like "cannot open source file string" are not related to your code, they are related to your project settings.

[image: VC2015]

Also note:

> Again, note that you should not add the dlib folder itself to your compiler's include path. Doing so will cause the build to fail because of name collisions (e.g. dlib/string.h with string.h from the standard library). Instead you should add the folder that contains the dlib folder to your include search path and then use include statements of the form #include . This will ensure that everything builds correctly.

Correct your includes. If E:\dlib-1.92.2\dlib is in your include path, then you should use: `#include <image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>`

To fix the cin/cout errors, use std::cin, std::cout and std::endl

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,but after the changes has been made errors have been decreased but still not able to run.I have attached a screenshot .Please have a look

Comment: Correct your includes. If E:\dlib-1.92.2\dlib is in your include path, then you should use: `#include <image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>`

To fix the cin/cout errors, use std::cin, std::cout and std::endl

Comment: Tried as you said ,but still it was not working so I kept E:\dlib-1.92.2 in include path and #include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h> ,now I am getting 1 error ,which I am not able to correct it.Help me ,Added recent screenshot.

Comment: Anyone please suggest what can do?

Comment: The path is wrong. base64_kernel_1.cpp ist not in ../base64/. You probably copied the dlib source dir to the wrong location.